# remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_gzd_template_single_shipping_costs_info', 7 ) does not work

Tags: php

Unfortunately, despite remove_action on the desired. page plus shipping costs. Does anyone know what this can do?

This is shown on my website. I want to remove it with php.

```
<p class="wc-gzd-additional-info">
<span class="wc-gzd-additional-info tax-info">inkl. 19 % MwSt.</span>
</p>
```

I already removed the title with

```
//remove product title only //This worked
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
```

Now I am trying to do the same but it does not work

```
<?php
/**
 * WooCommerce Custom Hook
 * woocommerce-hooks.php
 */

//remove product title only //This worked
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );

remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_single_shipping_costs_info', 7 )

// include plugin functions
include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
```

Comment: english please. Also show an [mcve]

Comment: Edit your question remove the german sentence and put in your english one. Also show the code as [mcve]